# Quiero renderizar una lista en un template

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
def main(request):
list=Hotel.objects.all()
template = get_template("index.html")
return HttpResponse(template.render({'list': list[0:max]}))
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
    {% for hotel in list %}
    <li>{{ hotel }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

La salida que obtengo es :

```
[<Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>, <Hotel: Hotel object>]
```

Y me gustaria:

. Nombre hotel 1

.Nombre hotel 2

Answer (score 3):

Suponiendo que tu modelo Hotel tenga un atributo llamado nombre (o name, o titulo...) tendrías que poner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
    {% for hotel in list %}
    <li>{{ hotel.nombre }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Ya que lo que te estás pidiendo que te renderice es el objeto en sí.

Puedes ver muchos ejemplos de cómo trabajar con plantillas con Django en [este enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)

Comment: Pongo hotel.name y me pasa igual

Comment: Tu plantilla y tu vista están bien, pero por lo que comentas te está imprimiendo 'list' y no renderizando index.html por lo que el error está en otro punto. ¿Has revisado que no se está produciendo algún conflicto con otras urls o vistas?

Comment: `def main(request):

    respuesta=""

    list=Hotel.objects.all()

    if len(list) == 0:

        print("Parsing....")
        theParser = make_parser()
        theHandler = myContentHandler()
        theParser.setContentHandler(theHandler)
        file = urllib2.urlopen( 'http://www.esmadrid.com/opendata/alojamientos_v1_es.xml')
        theParser.parse(file)
    
    template = get_template("index.html")
    print list[0].name
    for hotel in list[0:max]:
        print hotel.name

    return HttpResponse(template.render({'list': list[0:max]}))`

Comment: @DiegoPayoMartinez, ¿Esta es una nueva versión de tu función main? ¿Podrías explicarlo editando tu pregunta e incluir esta nueva función para verlo más claro todos y poder ayudarte con el problema? gracias :)